# How to modify this row on the mysql table

Tags: mysql

Check this table mysql.

http://goo.gl/Zcsppu

How can i modify field "target_type" in column "default" ,to change "null" to "0" ?

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `campaign_log` CHANGE COLUMN `target_type` `target_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL